# how to combine the first 2 column in pandas/python with n/a value

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have some questions about combining the first 2 columns in pandas/python with n/a value
long story: I need to read an excel and alter those changes. I can not change anything in excel, so any change has been done by python.

Here is the excel input

[image]

and the expected expect output will be

[image]

I manage to read it in, but when I try to combine the first 2 columns, I have some problems. since in excel, the first row is merged, so once it is read in. only one row has value, but the rest of the row is all N/A.

such as below:

```
Year   number  2016
Month          Jan
Month          2016-01
Grade   1      100
NaN     2      99
NaN     3      98
NaN     4      96
NaN     5      92
NaN   Total    485
```

Is there any function that can easily help me to combine the first two columns and make it as below:

```
 Year        2016
Month        Jan
Month        2016-01
Grade 1       100
Grade 2       99
Grade 3       98
Grade 4       96
Grade 5       92
Grade Total   485
```

Anything will be really appreciated.

I searched and google the key word for so long but did not find any answer that fits my situation here.

Comment: could you include the DF constructor of the sample you have there?

Comment: Hi, what is DF constructor? if you can see the three df, that is what the df looks like now, and I want to achieve the result as the last df in the post. please let me know if you are still confused! Thank you

Comment: post the result of `df.to_dict()`

Comment: I run df.to_dict(), it did not show anything, just straight to Process finished with exit code 0.

Comment: how did you get the df following "such as below:". is it copied from excel? from jupyter notebook?

Comment: for the such as below, I just read it from thee first 1 ( directly read excel). so the first pic is what it looks like in excel, and the three df is what it get read into python by pandas. 2 pic is what I want it to look like in excel, last df is what I try to achieve. probably I should remove the 1 and 2 pic from excel. I think it maybe a bit confusing.

Comment: "three df is what it get read into python by pandas". Right, so post the outcome of `print(three_df.to_dict())` here

Comment: {'Year': {0: 'Month', 1: 'Month End', 2: 'Month', 3: 'Grade', 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan}
{'number': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4, 7: 5, 8: 'Total' }
2016: {0: 'Jan', 1: datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 31, 0, 0), 2: '2016-01', 3: 100, 4: 99, 5: 98, 6: 96, 7: 92, 8: 485}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = '''
Year,number,2016
Month,,Jan
Month,,2016-01
Grade,1, 100
NaN,2, 99
NaN,3, 98
NaN,4, 96
NaN,5, 92
NaN,Total,485
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d))
df
```

[image]

```
df['Year'] = df.Year.fillna(method='ffill')
df = df.fillna('')   # skip this step if your data from excel does not have nan in col 2.
df['Year'] = df.Year + ' ' + df.number.astype('str')
df = df.drop('number',axis=1)
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am getting this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: I've update the answer.  Our data source are different.  So in your case, you need to change to str...   df['Year'] = df.Year + ' ' + df.number.astype('str')

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed the str without the '. and it worked!

Comment: I've update again .. just now was missing the '.